# complile tensorflow with bazel error: tensorflow_cc library not found

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel

I'm compiling tensorflow with bazel to a audio neural network source-separation model in C++. ([spleeterpp](https://github.com/loretoparisi/spleeterpp)). I wrote [this](https://github.com/loretoparisi/spleeterpp/blob/master/Dockerfile) Dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    unzip \
    rsync \
    gcc \
    build-essential \
    software-properties-common \
    cmake

# spleeterpp source
WORKDIR spleeterpp
COPY . .

# bazel install
RUN wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.25.2/bazel-0.25.2-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
RUN bash bazel-0.25.2-installer-linux-x86_64.sh

# tensorflow bazel build
RUN git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git && \
    cd tensorflow && \
    git checkout v1.14.0 && \
    rm BUILD
RUN cd tensorflow && \
    python tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py install && \
    mv build build-bu && \
    git checkout BUILD && \
    ./configure 

# build tensorflow to bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so
RUN cd tensorflow && \
    bazel build --config=monolithic --jobs=6 --verbose_failures //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so

# tensorflow install
ENV INSTALL_DIR=install
ENV INCLUDE_DIR=$INSTALL_DIR/include

RUN cd tensorflow && \
    mkdir -p $INSTALL_DIR/bin && \
    cp bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so* $INSTALL_DIR/bin/ && \
    mkdir -p $INSTALL_DIR/include && \
    rsync -a --prune-empty-dirs --include '*/' --include '*.h' --exclude '*' tensorflow/ $INCLUDE_DIR/tensorflow && \
    mkdir -p $INSTALL_DIR/include/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/ && \
    cp -r ./bazel-tensorflow/external/eigen_archive/unsupported/Eigen $INSTALL_DIR/include/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen && \
    cp -r ./bazel-tensorflow/external/eigen_archive/Eigen $INSTALL_DIR/include/third_party/eigen3/Eigen

# spleeterpp build
RUN mkdir build && cd build && \
    cmake -DTENSORFLOW_CC_INSTALL_DIR=$INSTALL_DIR/bin/ .. && \
    cmake --build .

# defaults command
CMD ["bash"]
```

I get the error

```
CMake Error at cmake/add_tensorflow.cmake:7 (message):
    tensorflow_cc library not found
```

The root path is the root project folder (where the `CMakeLists.txt` file is), while the install path for tensorflow Bazel build is `$INSTALL_DIR`, so I was expecting to have the static library in `$INSTALL_DIR/bin/` where it was copied before, so I set `cmake -DTENSORFLOW_CC_INSTALL_DIR=$INSTALL_DIR/bin/`, but it does not work.

Comment: Could you try to install your builded lib? Like `sudo make install` after the execution of your cmake which if I'm understanding correct will also call build process.

Comment: @YevheniiMamontov but where? The error comes when running last docker layer `RUN mkdir build && cd build && \...`